# What GIS software did you purchase to work with Tiger data?

Tags: shapefile, tiger

It looks like in Tiger line file the user must have mapping or Geographic Information System (GIS) software that can import TIGER/Line data. Has anyone worked with the TIGER/Line data. What GIS software did you purchase? Please advice the steps that I need to follow to map the data.

Comment: ESRI ARCGIS - TIGER is in ESRI Shapefile format and so native to ArcView/ArcGIS - http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2011/tgrshp2011.html

Comment: I am new to TIGER file and I have to work with state of Illinois only. I was able to download the zip file which had the project, shp, dbf, xml file. But what do I need to do with that file? I have a list of students with zipcode and I need to map them to the legislative and senate district, fullname of the senator and legislators and their address. I am still struggling on the steps that I need to follow in order to complete the project.

Comment: What is your usage purpose of the data?

Answer (score 4):

You can use QGIS to work with Tiger data.

It's not the newest but this video shows how to get QGIS and load Tiger: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQdMTXEFtaA

Comment: What would be the steps to work on this project. Download the tiger file, add vector layer and then how do I map the zipcode of my students to that file in QGIS. I also need to export the file that has mapped the zipcode with their legislatures and senators.

Comment: @ChitrarekhaSaha - It seems that you have a number of different questions for how to do this project.  This site is set up to handle individual questions, and have people answer them.  It might work better for you if you try to take the advice provided above, and then if you encounter further questions in your process, post those separately.  This also helps when people are searching for information, so they don't select a question and find that it contains something unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS will also work with TIGER data.